# Keras How to change input shape to 3 dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I print data from `print(X_test_t)` it show output like this.

```
[[[0.64088395]]]
```

I predict data with this code.

```
data = []

data.append(model.predict(X_test_t))
print(data)
```

It show output like this.

```
[array([[0.6424338]], dtype=float32)]
```

How to change `0.6424338` to `[[[0.6424338]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that 'data' is in 2 dimensions (because you used append function, if you use data.extend() data will be 1 dimensional vector)(refer the difference between append() and extend())

There are two approaches in your case.

1.

```
data.extend(model.predict(X_test_t))
data = [[data]]
print(data)
```

2.

```
data.append(model.predict(X_test_t))
data = [data]
print(data)
```

Both approaches may have different results when you predict multiple values at once